# What is the cost of health care in the US?

Tags: united-states, medical-bill, medicare

I was surprised to read articles about the cost of health care in the US. So, I became interested in this topic.

**My question;**

> - What is the cost of health care in the US?

That would depend on the availability of insurance, but I'd like to get a rough idea.

According to [this](https://halmek.co.jp/culture/c/hobby/2023) article (written in Japanese), in the United States;

- If you visit a doctor for the treatment of a cold it costs $1000.
  (In Japan, it's typically less than $30 if you use insurance.)
- If you transported to the ER it costs over $10,000,
  (Even in Japan, if you don't have insurance, it could cost this much money.)
- Hospitalization costs $2,000 to $3,000 per night (not including surgery), (If you have insurance, it's about $200 in Japan.）
- Relatively simple surgery, like an appendectomy, costs $10,000 to $35,000 dollars (If you have insurance, $2000 in Japan)
- Surgery for a serious disease can cost more than $100,000.

In addition, you must also pay $400 a month for even cheap private health insurance. If you use this course, all out-of-pocket until your medical bills reach $4,000. A course without a cutoff point would require a payment of $1,300 per month. (In Japan, the cost of an insurance capable of covering reasonable medical care for the entire family should be roughly $300 per month.)

**Note;**
I am not very good at English. I am sorry if I have used rude or unclear words. Corrections are welcome.

This question was originally [posted](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/60539/35256) on the Politics Stack Exchange, but was manually moved here on the advice that the Money category is more appropriate.

Comment: Welcome new user. Your English is perfect. (FYI many of the numbers are way too high as outlined in the answers.)

Comment: @Fattie　Thanks for the comment. The media, both in Japan and the US, exaggerate the bad side of politics. I don't believe it at face value either. But what bothers me is the variation in opinion about the prices listed in the article I quoted. Some say "it's an exaggeration" and others say "I basically agree with it. In Japan, there is an official price for health care and my question can be resolved by quoting the official price from the government's web page. How does it work out in the US?

Comment: Something important to keep in mind with the answers you are given is that prices can vary drastically in the US -- an ambulance ride can be thousands to tens of thousands for one person and 100 for an identical service depending on insurance.  I'm quite confident that the prices in your article have occurred, even if it might not be the norm.

Comment: @eps There appear to be at least three factors that affect prices: the cost of the medical care itself, compensation by insurance, and compensation from taxes. In any case, you'd have to combine all of these to get a fair comparison. The issue is surprisingly complex, so we'll take a step-by-step approach to understanding it. Next we want to focus on insurance. I have opened that stack [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/133199/104216). I  welcome your answers .

Comment: I know that it's actually illegal in some states for the doctors office to tell you the cost of a service if you are on insurance. That's why when you ask, they respond with "who are you insured with?" When billed through insurance, an MRI can cost $2500 or more, but when paying cash directly, it can cost as little as $300. Doesn't take much to turn on the machine, take some scans and send them to the doctor.

Comment: @coblr Thanks for the comment. The differences between the states are also an issue. It's also an amazing story about charging a higher price for having insurance.

I got dizzy and was taken by ambulance to a Japanese hospital for an MRI.
The total cost of the MRI and ER was $100.
The ambulance is free in Japan.
 In that sense, I feel 300$ is a bit high.　However, an MRI scan without medical necessity for health care purposes would cost about $400 in japan, so it might be reasonable in that sense.

Comment: Wow, it sounds like health care costs in Japan are quite high, if even the insured have to pay a lot out-of-pocket for basic health services.

Comment: Why would you go to a doctor for a cold?  There is nothing a doctor can do for a cold that you can't do yourself with a few OTC/home remedies.

Comment: @jamesqf　There is a difference between Japan and the US when it comes to OTC. In Japan, the scope of OTC is very narrow. Recently, antihistamines of some strength have become available as OTCs. However, it is cheaper to get a prescription from a doctor. In Japan, OTC is not covered by insurance. What about in the US?

Comment: @einpoklum In Japan, the premium for a typical family would be $600 per month for the entire family. 300 of which is paid by the employer. As a result, they are only required to pay 30% of the medical costs. Each month's medical costs are capped at $10,000.The discussion on insurance is divided [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/133199/104216).

Comment: @BlueVarious: Interesting. So, it's not hugely expensive, it's just skewed against the poor, who can't afford the co-payments.

Comment: @einpoklum Some say the cost of health care in the US is about the same as in Japan, while others say it is exorbitant. There is so much variety that I wonders if they are really from the same country. But I've never heard anyone say that it's much cheaper than in Japan. Can you tell me on a case-by-case basis what  the cost is? Your insurance and other conditions if possible.

Comment: @einpoklum Is health care expensive only for the poor who can't pay for insurance? I think there are system like Medicaid for the poor. Anyway, it seems to be an [insurance topic](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/133199/104216).

Comment: Why are you comparing costs with insurance against costs without insurance? Do you want to know the cash price or the insurance price?

Comment: @Blue Various: Can't say I know exact prices, but if you get e.g. WalMart generic stuff, antihistamines/decongestants might cost something like $5-10 (that's total, for the several you might buy for a cold), but that would be enough to treat several colds. But for me (note: I am not a doctor!), things like chicken soup, pickled ginger, a bit of wasabi, or other home remedies seem to work just as well.

Comment: @BlueVarious , "The ambulance is free in Japan."  That would be like an American saying "the military is free in America!"  Tax, tax, tax.  Also, has been mentioned endlessly, it is incredibly pointless to confuse cash costs with insurance costs.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I’m voting to close this question because while very interesting, these many "comparative economics" questions have, literally, no connection in any way to "personal finance".  Perhaps they should be moved to, say, the politics site which is about such *discussions*. This site is for answerable questions about - for example - "how to use my checkbooks". A trans-Pacific economic segment comparison is really totally unrelated to this site.

Comment: @Kat Thanks for your comment.
I asked the question under the assumption that it was  similar to the Japanese system, so the question was a bit poorly designed. In Japan, there is an official price for health care, and the price changes are quite simple depending on the availability of public insurance.
I guess the answer is that the cost of health care in the US, with or without insurance, fluctuates wildly depending on the conditions.

Comment: @Fattie Indeed, if we're going to compare systems, it's unfair if we don't at least take into account the "price of health care itself", "price of ambulances etc.", "payment for insurance", "cover depending on insurance" and "taxes". To take the discussion further, it becomes, as you say, a matter of comparative economics. I think it would be a subject in this category if it were "how do I avoid going bankrupt as a result of me being carried into the hospital?"

Comment: @jamesqf  I think the OTC system is more reasonable in the US than in Japan. People who could essentially be treated with OTC alone would visit clinics, though, so people who really should be in the hospital could be treated at a lower cost, in Japan.

Comment: Anyway, from now on, let's focus on the theme of the risk of going bankrupt from hospital visits. The information provided here also gives a variety of ideas, including using OTC, using good insurance, refusing to be treated out of network, and treating potentially expensive illnesses in Mexico.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The most important thing to keep in mind is that billing in the US healthcare system is utterly insane.  Identical procedures and even medication prices can vary wildly in price depending on where you get the service performed and the specifics of your insurance. We aren't talking about small differences here, we are talking about things that can vary by 10's of thousands of dollars.  There's no doubt in my mind that someone has gotten, for example, a bill for cold treatment that was $1,000.  In fact, some insurers pay the people they insure to obtain their medication or have an MRI done at certain places rather than others, because the cost to them is so drastically different.  Or even to go to a different country:

https://www.usnews.com/news/best-states/articles/2018-11-01/utah-insurance-company-is-paying-people-to-pick-up-their-prescriptions-in-mexico

Vox journalist Sarah Kliff did some excellent reporting on billing discrepancies, I highly encourage you to look up her work.  Here's some of an interview she did with NPR:

https://www.npr.org/2019/03/13/702975393/why-an-er-visit-can-cost-so-much-even-for-those-with-health-insurance

> This is FRESH AIR. I'm Terry Gross. You wouldn't believe what some emergency rooms charge, or maybe you would because you've gotten bills. For example, one hospital charged $76 for Bacitracin antibacterial ointment. One woman who fell and cut her ear and was given an ice pack but no other treatment was billed $5,751. My guest, Sarah Kliff, is a health policy journalist at vox.com who spent over a year investigating why ER bills are so high even with health insurance and why the charges vary so widely from one hospital to the next.

Here is a particularly gross example:

> KLIFF: Yeah. So this patient, his name is Justin. He was a community college student in northern California, was walking down a sidewalk in downtown San Francisco one day. And there was a pole hanging off the back of the bus that wasn't where it's supposed to be. It essentially flew off the back of the bus, hit him in the face and knocked him unconscious.

> And the next thing he knows, he's waking up at Zuckerberg San Francisco General, which is the only Level I trauma center in the city. He ends up needing a CT scan to check out some brain injuries. He needs some stitches. And then he's discharged. He ends up with a bill for $27,000.

> But, you know, as I began figuring out through my reporting, San Francisco General does not contract with private insurance, and they end up pursuing him for the vast majority of that bill. He has $27,000 outstanding. And somewhat ironically, San Francisco General, it is the city hospital. It is run by the city of San Francisco. So this student is hit by a city bus, taken by an ambulance to the city hospital and ends up with a $27,000 bill as a result.

> GROSS: So did he have insurance?

> KLIFF: **He did.** He had insurance through his dad.

Having insurance, even good insurance, is not even enough (as this example shows).  And what makes it all worse is that is actually very hard to make an informed price decision because it's very hard to figure out ahead of time if your insurance will cover something, and if they will how much procedure x will cost at facility y.

So tldr, your question:

> What is the cost of health care in the US?

The sad truth is that it's basically impossible to answer this question. Your ambulance ride might be free.  It might be a hundred bucks. It might be literally 10's of thousands of dollars.

https://abcnews.go.com/Health/doctor-56000-bill-air-ambulance-ride-accident-atv/story?id=58125900

> Groggy from painkillers, **Khan managed to ask the doctors how much the flight would cost and whether it would be covered by his insurer.** “I think they told my friend, ‘He needs to stop asking questions. He needs to get on that helicopter. He doesn’t realize how serious this injury is,'” Khan recalled.

> Total bill: $56,603 for an air ambulance flight. Blue Cross Blue Shield of Texas, Khan’s insurer, paid $11,972, after initially refusing altogether; the medevac company billed Khan for the remaining $44,631.

This is hardly uncommon -- there are many incidents of people refusing medical services because they are terrified of what the bill will end up being.

Comment: I wondered that so many people in this stack give such a wide variety of answers that I wonder if they are the same American. One person said the cost of health care in the US is extremely high, while another said it is not. This seemed to be more of a difference of fact of actual experience than a difference of opinion.
Your answers are great for getting to the essence of this and for giving evidence based on objective research. So I changed the best answer.

Comment: @BlueVarious Thank you for your comment.  I think this is also why it's very hard to change the system and why you see such wide ranging opinions on it -- for many middle to upper class people, healthcare in the US is fine.  They have good insurance from their employer (who foots most the bill) and don't need to use it that much anyway.  For others (poorer or sicker people) the system is an utter disaster.

Comment: I'd be very happy to get your response on  well.https://money.stackexchange.com/q/133199/104216

Comment: I can vouch for it being impossible to get a price ahead of time. Even in the case where you have the ability to call around first, pretty much nobody will give you a price before you come in, and they will act like you are an alien for asking.

Comment: Not American myself, but I've also read that there are a lot of shenanigans in the billing process.  SImply asking for an itemized receipt of services rendered and supplies used in your treatment can sometimes trim thousands of dollars off the total amount.

Comment: @Kat  That's probably the biggest problem. 　In Japan,  in most cases they will respond if you ask "Please let me know if you think it will cost more than $100." It seems to me that Americans more likely to go bankrupt from a sudden back injury than from stocks.

Comment: There is also a question about the npr's article: why would a patient who could be treated with a bandage or an ice pack go to the ER? Reading it over dispassionately, it seems to contain some unnatural. Why did they use the ER instead of  family doctor/General practitioner's clinic? Certainly, $5,751 for an ice pack is abnormal for any reason.

Comment: @BlueVarious The major reason is that most people are not doctors and cannot determine what level of care is appropriate in advance of seeing a doctor-- if you're not sure how badly you're hurt, the ER is a safer choice. And if you're picked up by an ambulance you may not be able to choose where you're taken. As for a family doctor or GP clinic, you aren't getting into one of those without an appointment; if you need care *today*, you can go to an ER or an urgent care facility (urgent care facilities are still relatively new, but are less expensive than ERs).

Comment: @Upper_Case 　Is there a concept of an appointment for family doctors or GP clinics? In Japan, appointments are only meant to reduce waiting time. I'm suffering from a sudden and severe back pain yesterday. There's an orthopedic clinic opening in four hours near me and I'm going to go there. If it's a hernia, I'll have to be prepared to pay a fair amount of money for it. But the risk of being unemployed in a declining economy is far greater than going bankrupt in hospital.

Comment: @BlueVarious Yes, and the situation you describe is the way that they're normally used in the US. But depending on where you live, there may be very few clinics like that and the soonest appointment may be weeks away (or longer!). You can generally get the same kinds of services in either setting, but getting those services in an ER is sometimes faster. If you feel you need emergency care, by all means go to an ER or urgent care center. But using an ER is by far the most expensive way to access medical services in the US.

Comment: @Upper_Case Surely everything would be different in the Arizona desert and New York. The important thing would be to live in a place where there is more than one home doctor/GP clinic available without an appointment, am I right?　Or maybe it's preferable to use a short term lump sum insurance policy when travelling to such places. I don't know how good travel insurance is for domestic travel, though.

Comment: @BlueVarious It's very complex, and the situation you describe as "the important thing" is difficult (if not impossible) to find in the US. Even if you did, there are other factors that matter-- an area with easy access to doctors might be more expensive to live in, for example, or the doctors might be more expensive. It might be easier to get a doctor's appointment in Manhattan than the desert of Arizona, but will be more expensive in Manhattan (like everything else) as well. There are no easy, efficient options for individuals to offset the US system's problems.

Comment: @ UPPER_CASE　Work, food, clothing and shelter. There's a lot more to think about than just healthcare.

Answer (score 20):

The US health care system has many maladies, and the absurd prices are only one effect of it. Most people don't pay those prices, as insurances negotiate the hospitals and doctors down, and the insurances have a lot of power.

The core concept is like this: let's say a procedure costs 40 $ to execute, and no doctor's office can survive on less. The insurance enforces that they pay only 20 $ for it, so the doctors office formally charges 2000 $ - for the majority of customers, they are forced to operate on a loss, and the small number of people that have no insurance (and have money) pay the full 2000 $, covering the losses from all others.

Add to this that the insurance industry uses around 65 % of all premiums to execute their job (which is negotiating prices with doctors, and declining payment requests from patients); only 35% are used for health related cost.

In addition, in the US, anyone can sue anybody for anything. Even if he might lose, the sued party needs to pay their lawyers, and if the suer has no money himself, there is no way to recover those lawyer cost. Combine that with the threat of easily multiple millions of damages if a doctor loses, and you see why every doctor must have *malpractice insurance*. These insurances are very expensive - for the reasons described - and cost hundreds of thousands per year for a small office.

Furthermore, ERs have to treat anybody that shows up, so they are always overloaded, and if the patients have no money to pay, the ER / hospital has to cover that cost, which - of course - is recovered from paying patients. That explains why an uncomplicated hernia surgery ends up with 70 000+$, and a difficult birth can easily cost far over a million.

As health insurance is not mandatory, and expensive, many healthier younger people don't have any, and just hope all goes well (or go in the ER). This risk 'unmixing' of course contributes also to higher insurance prices.

**Update**: I have been asked for sources.

- The 65% were from an article that I read years ago; I cannot find it anymore. Here is a link to a newer one that names 34.2%: https://www.healio.com/news/primary-care/20200106/a-third-of-us-health-care-spending-stems-from-administrative-costs
- the 70 000 are from my own hernia surgery. There is a 62 222.00 bill for the surgery itself, plus a 7000+ bill from the executing doctor, plus some smaller others.[image]
- the million for childbirth is from a bill a friend of mine got, for a complicated childbirth. I have no access to the original bill, but I have seen it.
- The 2000 $ is an example taken from a standard lab test (Quest, LabCorp). I annually get a bill for around that amount, reduced by my insurance to 38.97 or so.

The majority of americans still think the US health care is one of the best in the world; not having seen any others, ignoring all international comparisons, and being strongly afraid from any government-pushed changes. This is a part of their understanding of 'Freedom' - the right to chose *not* to have health insurance, vs any government mandate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "That explains why an uncomplicated hernia surgery ends up with 70 000+$"  is really? 　Hopefully this is a typo. If true, it's the US health care system that most needs to go to the hospital. A million dollars can buy a mansion. Can a common man afford that kind of money? Isn't that higher than their lifetime income?

Comment: The numbers in your answer are absurdly incorrect.  Doctors do not charge $2,000 for procedures that have $40 of overhead to people who do not have insurance  nor do people pay the full $2,000.  Nor does the  insurance industry use around 65% of all premiums to execute their job.  Numbers vary from study to study but studies suggest that billing and insurance-related services alone comprise about 15 percent of health care spending and total administrative costs are 25-30%.

Comment: I think this answer needs to be improved by adding sources for all of these claims.

Comment: Insurance companies are required by law to direct at least 80% of premium revenue towards healthcare costs, the rest they can use towards administrative purposes, marketing, overhead, and profits. I'm not sure where that 35% figure came from.

Comment: AxiomaticNexus - The 35% figure comes from pre-Obamacare numbers.  Yes, you're right about the requirement **to spend at least 80 percent of premium dollars on claims and activities to improve health care quality. 85% in large group markets** (85/15 for large groups).  Some grandfathered plans don't have to meet all of the ACA requirements.  Many of the stats in this answer are anecdotal and incorrect.

Comment: The dollar amount that a doctor bills an insurance company is a fantasy number.  He could bill $1,000 or $20,000.  The contract has a schedule of reimbursement regardless of the billed amount.  For uninsured patients, the fantasy amount does not apply.

Comment: I had the impression that the nominal costs of procedures was inflated in the US, not to make up for people who don't pay, but to allow insurance companies to show a benefit.  So if a hospital could do a procedure for $40 they (after many game theory iterations) give it a nominal price of $200 and give the insurance companies a 60% discount.  The hospital makes $80 and is happy.  The insurance companies can point to the massive savings they make for their customers.  Insurance becomes effectively mandatory for everyone that can afford it.  Aside from the invented numbers is this inaccurate?

Comment: That's very interesting. Similar surgery in a private and most expensive clinic in Ukraine would cost about ~20,000 UAH. It's about 700 USD. Flight to Ukraine can cost maybe 1,000-1,500 USD, not sure.

Comment: @BobBaerker The "fantasy amount" absolutely does apply, if it's what's listed on the charge master. Facilities usually have offsets for those with uninsured patients, but not always. I'm not necessarily endorsing any of the numbers in this answer, but the idea that the charge master price can't be shockingly high and/or inappropriate for the underlying service is not correct.

Answer (score 10):

Many of your numbers are exaggerations:

> - If you visit a doctor for the treatment of a colds cost ＄1000. (In Japan, it's typically less than ＄30 if you use insurance.)

With my doctor an office visit is $100 without insurance and $10 with insurance. My last prescription for a visit a few months ago was $5 for a 14 day course.

> - Hospitalization costs ＄2,000 to ＄3,000＄ per night (not including surgery), （If you have insurance, it's about ＄200 in Japan.）

With insurance it is much lower.

> - Relatively simple surgery, like appendectomy, costs 10 thousand to 35 thousand dollars, and (If you have insurance, ＄2000 in Japan)

My son had outpatient knee surgery a few years ago. It was less than $10,000 before insurance and less than $500 with insurance. That included the pre-surgical visit, the surgery, the post-op visit, and 10 physical therapy sessions.

or they are too broad:

> - If you transported to the ER costs over 10 thousand dollars, (Even in Japan, if you don't have insurance, it could cost this much money.)

But why are you in the ER: a minor reason? A broken bone? a heart attack? With my insurance it is $250 for the ER. If I go to an Urgent Care it is $100.

> - Surgery for a serious disease can cost more than 100 thousand dollars.

Again what surgery?

There are different ways that people get insurance In the United States. The way most people get coverage is though their employer. This disconnects most people from the full cost of the premiums and what the cost would be if they didn't have insurance.
In addition the premiums are tax deductible for the employee and the employer.

Other people get insurance on their own, or through government run portals. Depending on their income level there can be government assistance, and/or tax credits.

Medical costs are complex. Some of the numbers you are throwing around mix apples and oranges. Some people pick plans that have a low monthly cost but a higher deductible out-of-pocket maximum. Others pick plans with a higher monthly cost, and lower deductible and out-of-pocket maximum. It depends on what you "know" you need coverage for this year.

The options we have, and the model we will use in the future is nothing but politics. Every part that is swimming in profits will want to protect what they have, everybody drowning in their costs will want to change, and many that are disconnected from the cost just want to keep their doctor.

The issue will always boil down to politics.

Comment: Very insightful. I'll add that while employer insurance makes things bearable, it also introduces pricing that's fairly bananas. Something worth 5 bucks elsewhere can easily "cost" 500 bucks, but after insurance is applied, it magically ends up at 50 bucks.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer. The problem depends on the cost of medical insurance. If, as the article I cited states, $1300/month coverage is required for the price of health care you are referring to, then there is still no denying the claim that the cost of health care in the US is prohibitively high. If you don't mind me asking, what is your monthly health insurance cost? I would also be grateful if you could tell me about the health insurance system on this 
 [stack](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/133199/104216).

Comment: What the  "It depends on what you "know" you need coverage for this year.” you mean?
Do you mean that Americans choose the best health insurance policy based on an expectation of their own health in the next year?

Comment: @BlueVarious - **YES** you can pay $1000 a month (or more) for family health insurance in the USA, if you are self-employed.  By the way, you can very easily *see lists of prices* online.  But you must bear in mind that wages - for professional people - are basically high in the US, and furthermore, don't forget that in many countries, the "medical tax" (whatever it is named) from the government can be ~10% or more of your income; in general (not always true) taxes are far lower in the US.

Comment: @Fattie But the “medical tax” in the US is also quite high. The US government spends more (as a proportion of GDP) on health care than the UK government does, it just spends it very inefficiently. And so you pay more taxes for government health care in the US than in the UK, but you need insurance as well.

Comment: @MikeScott , i think with topics like this one can endlessly go back and fore on different parts of the topic!  The whole "what does each country waste on healthcare" question is indeed fascinating (but does it relate to what the OP asks?)  I suggest making a new answer with these points!

Comment: The focus here is certainly on the issue of the costs patients have to pay for medical treatment. Let's solve them one by one. As for insurance, let's move into this [stack](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/133199/104216).

Comment: As a "worse case scenario" I can see someone getting a 1k bill for a cold if they were unlucky and went to an out of network hospital.

Comment: @eps Thanks for your comment. It seems to be one thing that the price of health care in the US  very widely depending on the situation. In Japan the government sets the cost of health care, but in the US it seems to be based on the principle of competition. People who have good insurance conditions do not think that medical care is expensive. On the other hand, those who have bad insurance think it is too expensive. Rather than a difference of opinion, this seems to indicate that the actual facts are different between the respondents.

Comment: +1 I'm sure *some* people *somewhere* do get outrageous bills, but my experience in the US is that insurance covers most things with a small deductible. And doctors/nurses in the US are a **lot** nicer and easier to access than in Europe or Canada.

Answer (score 7):

I can give one illustration:

Some years ago I had a kidney stone attack while on a trip to Mississippi (from Minnesota).  I checked into the emergency room of the local hospital and eventually, after about 24 hours, was given surgery to remove the stone.  Everything went pretty well (though I'll admit to being somewhat confused by the procedures there vs back in Minnesota).

Anyway, when I got home and got the bill several weeks later I found that the hospital had given me (and my insurance company) about an 80% discount off the bill total (though note that the surgeon billed things separately).

I actually called the hospital since I thought there must be something wrong -- I can see a 20% discount, but 80% makes no sense.  But they assured me that the numbers were correct, and everything went through without a hitch (with my ins co paying most of the remaining 20%).

This made me realize that there was something of a game going on there, with the providers faking higher rates so that the ins co can seem to be getting really good deal for consumers.  (And it probably somehow fiddles with the amount the insurance companies claim they pay as well.)  I suspect that often this "discount" is hidden, to make insurance clients think they're getting a really good deal.

And I've never been able to find confirmation, but I suspect that a similar game is going on with drug prices.  Drug companies jack up the prices ridiculously high, then give insurance companies an under-the-table discount.

Net-net: There is very little transparency in pricing of drugs and medical services in the US.  This leads to (sadly) ridiculous inequity in the costs of medical services.

Answer (score 4):

**In summary:**

Some points from the article are "utterly ridiculous"; some are "unrealistic".

- If you visit a doctor for the treatment of a colds cost ＄1000. (In Japan, it's typically less than ＄30 if you use insurance. )

Utterly ridiculous.

**It is $90 to $120.**  (BUT you get a sharp discount if you are a "cash patient".)  With insurance it is $5 to $20.

- If you transported to the ER costs over 10 thousand dollars, (Even in Japan, if you don't have insurance, it could cost this much money.)

This is a **huge exaggeration or an extreme case**. An ambulance is expensive, maybe 1 or 2 thousand.

- Hospitalization costs ＄2,000 to ＄3,000＄ per night (not including surgery), （If you have insurance, it's about ＄200 in Japan.）

This is the **"upper end of the scale"**. "$1,000" could be more typical.

- Relatively simple surgery, like appendectomy, costs 10 thousand to 35 thousand dollars

That's about right.

- Surgery for a serious disease can cost more than 100 thousand dollars.

Meaningless, many "serious" surgeries (transplants etc) are nominally millions of dollars.

- Insurance

Can easily google some prices: https://www.ehealthinsurance.com/resources/individual-and-family/how-much-does-individual-health-insurance-for-self-employed-people-cost

Yes, it's **not unusual to pay 10 or even 15 thousand a year**, if you are self-employed, for **health insurance for a family**. It's a, or the, major cost.

(But don't forget in many countries, the "medical tax" (whatever it is named) from the government can be ~10% or more of your income.)

**Drastic *"disparity from nominal"* of prices in the US system:**

As others have explained, it's difficult to "state the price" of medical service X in the US.  A hospital system will state "Oh, that is $7,201" - but the number is all-but meaningless. In reality, the hospital will do 1,452 of those procedures in a given year, for, insurance company Y, and, that company will negotiate some price for the procedure - and that number can be utterly different from the nominal "$7,201".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If an uninsured tourist gets sick in the US and gets treated, would a nominal price be applied? Or is it possible to negotiate a price?

Comment: hi @BlueVarious - you are wildly adding new and different aspects to the question - political, practical, economic, etc!  Suggest ask new question(s) on this (or perhaps the travel, politics, or economics sites)

Comment: This was a question about the "nominal price"  you said. Indeed, the question I added seems to be closer to this [issue](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/133199/104216). Oh, sorry!! If you can, I would be happy to get an answer to this [stack](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/133199/104216).

Comment: @BlueVarious : you can always negotiate, and your chances are good to get a significant reduction. They are used to not getting the amounts they print on the bill.

Comment: @Aganju Thanks for your comments. It seems that there is room to negotiate prices and some say there is not. The American system is a complex one.

Comment: As a "worse case scenario" I can see someone getting a 1k bill for a cold if they were unlucky and went to an out of network hospital.  Something important to keep in mind is that prices can vary drastically in the US -- an ambulance ride can be thousands to tens of thousands for one person and 100 for an identical service depending on insurance.

Comment: @BlueVarious When I was exchange student in the US, I had to go to the hospital. Ended up with a 10k+ bill. I went to the hospital Billing Officer (or whatever their title is), cried for 5 minutes in their office as I could barely afford it, and they offered me a 20% discount (saying something along the line _“it's the best I can do”_), with no other basis that I “negotiated”. So yes, prices are variable… and as they're a for-profit, they'll always prefer that you pay 80% rather than having to hire a debt collector with no insurance of getting their money back.

Comment: Average hospital stay is $10k over 4.5 days, > $2000/day: https://www.hcup-us.ahrq.gov/reports/statbriefs/sb180-Hospitalizations-United-States-2012.pdf
Average doctor visit is > $250 in 2017: https://consumerhealthratings.com/healthcare_category/doctors-charges-physician-prices-average-cost-anesthesia/ Of course, only guarantee about US health care pricing is that it goes up every year.

Comment: +1 to mentioning that high medical taxes in other countries. I hate to see people claiming that something is "free" in Europe or Japan - no its not, you're just paying for it differently.

Comment: @JonathanReez The US government spends more on health care as a proportion of GDP than the UK does. In the US, you both pay a lot in tax for very inefficient government health care _and_ also have to pay for insurance.

Comment: @MikeScott I live in the US (Washington) and pay 2x less tax than I would in the UK for an equivalent salary. My insurance gets me a hospital experience FAR superior than anything the NHS could offer, for a fraction of the cost - my employer spends ~3% of my pretax salary on the insurance policy.

Comment: @JonathanReez But your lower tax is because of less other government spending, not less health spending. And I bet your insurance costs more than £3K per year, which is the approximate cost of the NHS per adult taxpayer.

Comment: @MikeScott if I had an equivalent salary in the UK I would pay more than $3k/year towards the NHS. And yes - I'm sure that the UK spends more on other things, but those aren't necessarily things I would personally benefit from.

Comment: the NHS is, usually, unspeakably horrible.